# MySQL drop a Table Named "trigger"

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, ddl, drop-table

I just created a MySQL Table called "trigger".
The Problem now:
I want to "`drop table trigger;`"
This is not working. (Syntax error...) because it recognizes trigger not as name but as a trigger.

How do I do drop a table Named "trigger"?

Comment: If reserved word is used as object name then it must be quoted with backticks: ```drop table `trigger`;```. But reserved words as object names usage is bad practice - do it never.

Comment: I am actually new to MySQL and had to learn it the hard way...

Comment: [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  Language Structure  /  Schema Object Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html) - study.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape a name with backticks. In your case:

```sql
DROP TABLE `trigger`;
```